# Invalid Attempt to access field before read

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have been beating my head over this all morning and I know it's probably some simple thing I'm just missing.  The code is breaking at the dr.getstring(1).ToString line with the error "Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read().  I know the SQL statement is good it works fine in workbench so I'm thinking their has to be something messed up with my parameter, it's just not erroring out there.

```
Dim cs As New MySqlConnection("SERVER=10.1.1.1;Persist Security Info=True;DATABASE=db;UID=uid;Password=pw")
    Dim ds As String = cs.DataSource
    Dim cn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = "user id=uid;password=pw!;database=db;data source=" + ds
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT a.email, b.details, b.requestor, b.id from department a, workrequest b WHERE a.name = b.department AND b.approval IS Null AND b.status != @stat"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@stat", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Closed"
    cn.Open()
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    While dr.Read() Or i < 20
        'Dim email As String = dr.GetString(0).ToString
        Dim email As String = "test@dom.an"
        Dim details As String = dr.GetString(1).ToString
        Dim requestor As String = dr.GetString(2).ToString
        Dim workid As String = dr.GetString(3).ToString

        Try
            SendSMTP("test.dom.am", email, "Work Request Awaiting Approval", "<body><b>Work Request Number:</b> " & workid & "</br><b> Referring to: </b></br> " & details & "</br><b>Submitted By: </b> " & requestor & "</br> Is waiting for your approval.  Please go to http://test.dom.an to view and approve or deny the request</body>", "test.dom.an", "")

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        i = i + 1
    End While
    Me.Close()
```

Comment: If `i > 20` but you are out of rows it will crash.  You wont know it because of the empty Catch.  I *think* you want `While dr.Read() AndAlso i < 20`

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you need to count till 20. However the error is a strong hint that your query doesn't return anything. The or operator allows your code to enter anyway in the loop but the reader has no rows.

Comment: I had the <20 just to limit how much I spam my own e-mail during testing.  It seems to have fixed that error by removing it.  Thanks for you help!